# Haskell how to get code from Hackage into project? Cabal install project failed

Tags: debugging, haskell, hackage

I created [a project in hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/print-debugger) that I want to import into my code.

Rather than manually copy-pasting the code from "[print-debugger-0.0.tar.gz](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/print-debugger-0.0/src/)" into the src folder of my cabal project, I want to be able to do this...

// project.cabal file

```
name:              project
...
executable project
  main-is:         Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:  src
  build-depends:   base, split, print-debugger
```

And do this...

```
cabal install print-debugger
```

And import "StackTraceDebug" into my project.

When I try I get messages...

```
"this package is not installed"
"cabal: There is no package named 'print-debugger'"
```

**How do I get my code out of hackage and into my project without manually copying and pasting?**

Comment: Well, if you *just* uploaded that package, you'll have to do `cabal update` to get it to see it. After doing a `cabal update` I can see your package, however it doesn't build (due to a missing source file). Perhaps you have placed something in the wrong directory?

Comment: @user2407038 - I did do "cabal update". I think my install of build-essentials from the Ubuntu 14.04 software repo is complete crap and I need to get rid of it and install something else.

Comment: Then run `cabal install print-debugger -v3` and see where exactly it fails.

Comment: @user2407038 - Can you try this out for me: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/print-debugger

Comment: Can't do it as you have listed `base <4.8.2.0` as a dependency and I don't have such an old compiler any more.

Comment: @user2407038 I don't understand. "base < 4.8.2.0" means that you can use any base that is less than 4.8.2.0 (the version of base that I am currently using). Do you want me to change it to "base =< 4.8.2.0"? I don't understand. Also, how/where do you specify the compiler? This project requires GHC 7.10.1 (or greater) because of the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry I may have misspoke. I have base-4.8.2.0, so `base<4.8.2.0` will not work for me but `base<=4.8.2.0` will. However, you probably want to specify a *lower* bound, not an upper one, for the first version which had stack traces. You can't specify the version of the compiler, but the version of the `base` library is completely tied to the compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though version 0.0 failed to install due to missing files (see: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/print-debugger-0.0/reports/1) but that later versions have fixed this issue and now things should work smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

If you have problems with `cabal`, you might consider trying [stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html) in the future. It's very helpful for coordinating dependencies between projects.

Comment: ^ Can you try this out for me:  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/print-debugger

Comment: I should have been clearer. `stack` uses https://www.stackage.org. Unless your package has been uploaded to stackage, you would need to add it to the `extra-deps` field in your `stack.yaml` config file for the project that uses it. Then it pulls it from hackage instead.